# Are there any limitations from using ANSI Functions in a Unicode Application

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, sqlite

I have a C++ Native WinAPI application that strictly uses Unicode functions and data types. Ie, CreateWindowW(), SendMessageW(), wstring, WCHAR, etc. Now I intend to expand my application  to use SQLite3.

**My Problem:** The SQLite3 library is ANSI. Which means I have to use `char*` as most function parameters.

**Are there any limitations or negative impacts from using ANSI Functions in a Unicode Application?**

If there are what might these impacts be?

Comment: The term "ANSI" is a misnomer (and unfortunately a common one). In this context, it refers to the 8-bit Windows-1252 code page and its relatives. These code pages were never ANSI standards. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_ANSI_code_page#ANSI_code_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No limitation, you can use ANSI strings in Unicode applications.

Some details: Unicode application is compile-time definition. At run time, program can work both with Unicode and ANSI strings.

For example:

```
char* ptr1;     // this is always ANSI string
wchar_t* ptr2;  // this is always Unicode string
TCHAR* ptr3;    // this is generic string, which is compiled as char* or wchar_t*
```

Unicode/ANSI configuration differs by interpreting a generic text macros, like `TCHAR`. Some Windows API are also implemented using generic text macros. For example: `SetWindowText` is actually macro, which is expanded to `SetWindowTextA` in ANSI configuration, and to `SetWindowTextW` in Unicode configuration.

Any non-generic string or API name (like `char*`, `SetWindowTextW` etc.) works by the same way in any program configuration.

Use ATL conversion macros to convert between different (generic and non-generic) string types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: `char*` is not always ANSI. (Also both 'ANSI string' and 'Unicode string' are misnomers; ANSI strings dont correspond to any specification created by the American National Standards Institute, and Unicode is not a particular string encoding.)

Comment: @bames53 - this is practical question, I prefer to give an answer and not to dispute about terminology.

Comment: @Alex I'd prefer an answer that was correct. The dispute is not about terminology. The error is this statement: "char* is always ANSI string".

Comment: Yes, my primary concern is that it is incorrect to state that `char*` is always ANSI. Even on Windows I typically write programs such that `char*` is always UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite is not restricted to ANSI. It is a misconception that `char*` implies ANSI encoded text. Not all functions that operate on `char*` data assume that the data is ANSI encoded. In the case of SQLite it fully supports Unicode and does so using `char*` data encoded using UTF-8.

If you intend to continue using UTF-16 encoded text internal to your application you'll need to add an adapter layer at the boundary between your code and the SQLite code. Convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 when passing data to SQLite, and the opposite direction when receiving.

Which to my mind renders the question that you asked somewhat moot, but I'll address that anyway:

> Are there any limitations or negative impacts from using ANSI Functions in a Unicode Application?

The most obvious drawbacks of using ANSI functions are:

1. Severely restricted character set.
2. Performance cost when converting between different character sets.
3. Risk of programmer confusion and errors due to using multiple character sets in a single codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ansi-based APIs in a Unicode application. Simply convert your input Unicode strings to Ansi when passing them to the API, and convert any output Ansi strings to Unicode upon return from the API. You can use `WideCharToMultiByte()` and `MultiByteToWideChar()` for that, or higher-level wrappers like `CString`, ATL conversions, etc.